# How to reset permissions for a user [Discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

I have looked through the documentation and have not been able to find a way to reset permissions or remove a users permissions for a voice channel. using this code:

```
member_permissions = channel.overwrites_for(member)
member_permissions.manage_channels = False
member_permissions.move_members = False
member_permissions.mute_members = False
await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=member_permissions)
```

this code sets all permissions to False, but I want it to remove the users permissions because when you set it to false it still shows in the voice channel permissions.

basically how to use this button in discord.py:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> If the `overwrite` parameter is `None`, then the permission overwrites are deleted.

So simply:

```py
await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=None)
```

[`GuildChannel.set_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.abc.GuildChannel.set_permissions)